# How many Bitcoins do i need to purchase an item of 100$

Tags: exchange-rate

I have 0.07942 in my alpha bay account and i cannot purchase an item retailing @ 100$.
How many more bitcoins do i need for the transaction to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Use public exchange rates to get the Dollar equivalent (e.g. Coindesk, Blockchain.info, Bitstamp, Bitfinex, etc.)